# How to Define all files individually in Transfomers Pipeline

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I have the GPT-Neo 125M model saved locally in a folder, the folder includes the Pytorch model, tokenizer and other config files. The following works perfectly.
`generator = pipeline(task= 'text-generation', model="local_directory")`

I want to do the same thing but without a directory in which every thing is stored.
I have all files in different locations and want to point to them individually.
Is it possible to do something like

`generator = pipeline(task= 'text-generation', model="path/to/model", config="path/to/configfile", tokenizer="/path/to/tokenizer)`

The reason why i cant use a Directory is because i am downloading all files individually from a server every time i run text generation.